# ¿Hay la manera de hacer un contador con varios botones?

Tags: javascript

estoy haciendo un ejercicio y necesito hacer un contador con varios botones, que cada botón me sume +1 si lo pulso, esto es lo mas lejos que he llegado a hacer pero no me sirve

```js
window.onload = function () {
  var contar = 0;
  const botones = document.querySelectorAll(".botonFin");
  botones.forEach((el) => {
    el.addEventListener("click", contar);
  });
};
function contar() {
  contar++;
  console.log(contar);
}
```

hay alguna forma de hacerlo?

Answer (score 2):

Es cuestión de unos pocos cambio.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var contador = 0;

  function contar() {
    contador++;
    console.log(contador);
  }

  const botones = document.querySelectorAll(".botonFin");
  botones.forEach((el) => {
    el.addEventListener("click", contar);
  });
};
```

```html
<button class="botonFin"> +1 </button>

<button class="botonFin"> +1 - x2 </button>
```

Basicamente estabas sobreescribiendo la función `contar` con la variable `contar`. Hay que cambiarle el nombre a `contador` para que no choque. También hay que meter la función contar al onload por que la variable `contador` esta dentro de ese scope.